# Offline messages are not consumed in Moquette with Paho Client

Tags: java, mqtt, paho, moquette

I have an issue with respect to consuming offline MQTT messages in Moquette server through eclipse Paho client.

Following are the steps which I have followed.

1. Created and spinned up the Moquette MQTT broker.
2. Created a simple MQTT consumer application using eclipse Paho client.
3. Set consumer to consume data on topic : "devices/reported/#" with QOS : 1 and CleanSession : False
4. Created a simple MQTT data publisher to publish data to MQTT broker using Eclipse Paho.
5. Used MQTT data publisher to publish messages to : "devices/reported/client_1" topic with QOS : 1

Above steps were successful without any issue.

Then I stopped my consumer application and sent MQTT data to broker with the same topic. using my publisher application - Server was able to receive these messages but in this moment there was no any consumer to consume this message since I have stopped my consumer.
Then I started my consumer application again. It was connected to the broker successfully but, it did not receive any message which I sent to broker while the consumer shutdown.

Do I need to do any specific configuration to my Moquette server to persist data (with clean session : false) ?
Or am I missing something ?

Please find my sample code below,

*Moquette Server initialization*

```
package com.gbids.mqtt.moquette.main;

import com.gbids.mqtt.moquette.server.PublishInterceptor;
import io.moquette.interception.InterceptHandler;
import io.moquette.server.Server;
import io.moquette.server.config.IConfig;
import io.moquette.server.config.MemoryConfig;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ServerLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        final IConfig configs = new MemoryConfig(props);

        final Server mqttBroker = new Server();
        final List<? extends InterceptHandler> userHandlers = Arrays.asList(new PublishInterceptor());
        mqttBroker.startServer(configs, userHandlers);

        System.out.println("moquette mqtt broker started, press ctrl-c to shutdown..");
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("stopping moquette mqtt broker..");
                mqttBroker.stopServer();
                System.out.println("moquette mqtt broker stopped");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*MQTT Consumer*

```
package com.gbids.mqtt.moquette.main;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.*;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class ConsumerLauncher implements MqttCallback {

    private static final String topicPrefix = "devices/reported";
    private static final String broker = "tcp://0.0.0.0:1883";
    private static final String clientIdPrefix = "consumer";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MqttException {
        final String clientId = "consumer_1";
        MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, new MemoryPersistence());
        MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connOpts.setCleanSession(false);
        sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
        sampleClient.subscribe(topicPrefix + "/#", 1);
        sampleClient.setCallback(new ConsumerLauncher());
    }

    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        System.out.println("Consumer connection lost : " + throwable.getMessage());
    }

    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Message arrived from topic : " + s + " | Message : " + new String(mqttMessage.getPayload()) + " | Message ID : " +mqttMessage.getId());
    }

    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        System.out.println("Delivery completed from : " + clientIdPrefix + "_1");
    }
}
```

*MQTT Publisher*

```
package com.gbids.mqtt.moquette.main;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.persist.MemoryPersistence;

public class ClientLauncher {

    private static final String content = "{\"randomData\": 25}";
    private static final String willContent = "Client disconnected unexpectedly";
    private static final String broker = "tcp://0.0.0.0:1883";
    private static final String clientIdPrefix = "client";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        sendDataWithQOSOne();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void sendDataWithQOSOne(){
        try {
            final String clientId = "client_1";
            MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, new MemoryPersistence());
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(false); // for publisher - this is not needed I think
            sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
            message.setQos(1);
            final String topic = "devices/reported/" + clientId;
            sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
            System.out.println("Message published from : " + clientId + " with payload of : " + content);
            sampleClient.disconnect();
        } catch (MqttException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you need to set the `retained` flag to `true` when creating the `MqttMessage` in your `ClientLauncher` (publisher). The default value is `false` as in the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttMessage.html#setRetained-boolean-).

```
...    
message.setRetained(true)
...
```

Setting this flag enables messages to be retained on the broker and be sent to newly connected clients. Please be aware, that the broker only keeps the last message for a topic. There is no way to keep more than one message for a specific topic.

Comment: Setting the retained flag only keeps the last message published (with the retained flag set) on a given topic. It does not queue messages for offline clients that have been previously subscribed to a topic.

Comment: @hardlib Yes of course it only keeps the last message. The OP did not state that ALL messages should be kept. If this is the case, MQTT is the wrong choice anyway, because MQTT is not designed for this. The Broker is to be understood as a kind of state database. (edited the answer to respect that)